# How do i calculate a time invariant scalar in R?

Tags: r, scalar

[image: Daniel Moskowitz Momentum Crashes]

[image]

So i need to calculate lambda, i already got the estimated return and the estimated Volatility of the next month. But how do i choose lamda? 
Do i just divide 19% by my volatility for every observation ? but why is it 1/2 then?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry for posting here